# Is there a difference between `moist` and `moisty`?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice

Could the extra y appended to "moist" result in an adjective with a significantly different meaning?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/moisty) calls _moisty_ 'archaic and informal'.

Comment: When asking such a question, include your own research (such as what you found in a dictionary).

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever, in 70 years, seen "moisty" (prior to just now).

Comment: People add y to mean "sort of". moisty means sort of moist. ish, is another  one that means "sort of". with moist, it is hard to say: moist-ish, moist**y** is easier.

Comment: @Rattler That's not how I interpret << archaic, informal >>. And the Google 1-gram shows a fairly strong recent usage.

Comment: I used to get all fired up about 'crispy', and called it an infantile invention of marketing people when selling us potato chips, etc, but I shut up when I found out how old it is.

Comment: @HotLicks  "I'm not sure I've ever, in 70 years, seen "moisty" - it sounds like something out of a Gilbert Sorrentino bad-writing pastiche.

Comment: It was all but obsolete till Steeleye Span used it in a lyric. https://mainlynorfolk.info/steeleye.span/songs/onemistymoistymorning.html

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I immediately thought of that verse too, not as a song but as a nursery rhyme in an old book I was given as a small child 60+ years ago. I don't think I've ever come across 'moisty' in any other context.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Yes! 60+ years ago we used to say, 'It's a misty moisty morning' whenever it WAS one. But I can't remember that book or where we got the words from. Maybe my mother used to sing it or read us it. Or was it on "Singing Together", the radio broadcast we had twice a week at school? The words of the Wiltshire Wedding Song are here: https://digital.nls.uk/special-collections-of-printed-music/archive/87636321  I did half remember "With many kind Embraces | I stroak'd her double Chin" !

Comment: @Kate Bunting Steeleye Span cut half the verses and changed the tune (of lines 5 & 6 and the chorus) from what's printed there. But maybe the printed version does go on a bit too long, and the tune runs out of steam. I doubt if any version of the original is still sung anywhere. Their version's here, by the way: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SacU_M1seD4)